# The connotation of "increasing dramatically"

Tags: meaning, phrases

I had a conversation with my co-worker, who said if I do X the quality of my work will improve dramatically. I took it as an implication that my initial work is low quality. Am I taking it the wrong way, or does "dramatically improving" have the connotation of a relatively low starting base? 
Neither is a native English speaker.

Comment: It simply implies increasing rapidly.  The starting point is not implied.

Comment: @HotLicks OTOH, if the quality is already great, there's not much room for dramatic improvement.

Comment: The phrase may or may not have that implication (or, strictly speaking, implicature); without knowing a great deal about the setting, subject matter, and the relationship between the people involved, it is impossible to tell.

Answer (score -1):

Your co-working is wrong. The quality will *improve* dramatically.

*Both* is also wrong. Use *Neither*.

Yes, you're taking it the wrong way. Your co-worker is giving you advice. That isn't an insult. Right or wrong, your co-worker is trying to help you.

Comment: I might be annoyed if a colleague implied that the quality of my work _could_ improve dramatically, because that would mean the quality was not close to maximum already. I would suspect they might be patronising me. Also it is OK to say that quality increases.

Comment: I'm confused by your first sentence: "co-working"? Why the emphasis on the word improve? Also, where does the word both fit into your answer?

Comment: @rhetorician The question has been edited to correct the grammatical mistakes that were not directly relevant to the question. It originally said "Both" instead of "Neither".

Comment: @me - "I would suspect they might be patronising me" or maybe just socially inept.

Comment: @rhetorician - _I'm confused by your first sentence: "co-working"?_ 1. I am fairly sure 'co-working' is a typo for 'co-worker'. 2. You should not end a statement with a question mark.